# How can I fix ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64?

Tags: c++, g++, x86-64

So I wrote a `Vector` class but there's this linker error that I don't know how to fix:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "operator<<(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, Vector<int> const&)", referenced from:
      _main in main-be9b4b.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Here's the code:

```
template<typename T>
class Vector {
public:
    Vector () {
        capacity = 1;
        data = alloc(capacity);
        size = 0;
    }

    Vector (size_t cap) : capacity(cap) {
        data = alloc(capacity);
        size = 0;
    }

    Vector (const Vector<T>& other) {
        capacity = other.capacity;
        size = other.size;
        data = alloc(capacity);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
            data[i] = other.data[i];
        }
    }

    Vector (Vector<T>&& other) {
        capacity = other.capacity;
        size = other.size;
        data = other.data;

        other.capacity = 0;
        other.size = 0;
        other.data = nullptr;
    }

    Vector& operator=(const Vector<T>& other) {
        Vector<T> tmp(other);
        swap(*this, tmp);
        return *this;
    }

    void push_back(T element) {
        ensure_space();
        data[size++] = element;
    }

    template<typename... Args>
    void emplace_back(Args&... args) {
        push_back(T(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
    }

    friend void swap(Vector<T>& v1, Vector<T>& v2);
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Vector<T>& v);
private:
    T* data;
    size_t capacity;
    size_t size;

    T* alloc(size_t cap) {
        return new T[cap];
    }

    void ensure_space() {
        if (size < capacity) return;
        T* tmp = alloc(capacity << 1);
        memcpy(tmp, data, size);
        delete[] data;
        data = tmp;
        capacity <<= 1;
    }
};

template<typename T>
void swap(Vector<T>& v1, Vector<T>& v2) {
    std::swap(v1.data, v2.data);
    std::swap(v1.capacity, v2.capacity);
    std::swap(v1.size, v2.size);
}

template<typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Vector<T>& v) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size; ++i) {
        out << v.data[i] << " ";
    }
    out << std::endl;
    return out;
}
```

Comment: "Here's the code" -- can you explain where, exactly, "here" is?

Comment: I think you may find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660123/overloading-friend-operator-for-template-class/4661372#4661372) an interesting read.

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42979725) to a related question helped to fix the problem.